Is there a way to create a website where it accepts an sql query to create a tab for result table and potential chart without mvc?
I am working with c# and MVC to create a website to present a dashboard which will display several charts and then show several tabs which represent different SQL queries. Each tab will display a table and if required a chart of the resulting Query. Using this approach is working fine and getting along fine with it.
However, I would like to know if I would like to make this dynamic where say you have like admin access and you want to create a query and then it will automatically create a tab for that and use the query/ies to display a chart (if required). I would like to also know if it is possible, then which project type in c# (visual studio) would I need to use to be able to design this.

Perhaps take a look at SQLpage - "Build Dynamic Websites with Just SQL Queries (ophir.dev)"
Ther was a discussion on Hacker news recently where some participants mentioned similar projects.

Thank you for the reply and the links. Are there any methods of utilising MVC for something like this project?
